# Add strings to an array of strings inside for loop using java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a for loop and I want to add strings to a string array inside that loop.

```
    String[] result = new String[5];
    for(int i=0; i<this.registration.length; ++i){ //need to start from index 1 for some calculation
        String stringResult = String.format("%s(%s)", this.registration[i].getMarks(), this.registration[i].getGrade());
    
        result = new String(){stringResult};
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

How can I achieve that? The output should look like this-

```
{100(A), 70(B),  0(F)}
```

Comment: can you share the class of a Registration object ? Of whatever class is contained in `this.registration` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `result` array with a size that matches the `registration` array length, since you know you want to create one result for each `registration` entry. You then can loop over the `registration` array, build the `stringResult` for a given index, and assign it to the corresponding index of the `result` array.

```
String[] result = new String[this.registration.length];
for (int i = 0; i < this.registration.length; ++i) {
    String stringResult = String.format("%s(%s)", this.registration[i].getMarks(), this.registration[i].getGrade());

    result[i] = stringResult;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: You have "reservation" for "registration" in one place, and unless the field is shadowed by a local variable, there is no need to qualify accesses to it with "this" (as OP did).

Comment: @DavidConrad My bad with the `registration`. I think the `this` should probably be left in, as it's just altering OP's code, which we do not know the surrounding context. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: Fair enough. I noticed you hadn't made another edit putting `this` back in from where I had taken it out, so I just put it back in.

Comment: thank you for the solution. it solved my problem!